# Firebase test web server?

Tags: firebase, webserver, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have switched to using Firebase for hosting my website, a welcome change from the mayhem that is AppEngine. I have been reading through the documentation and have seen that Firebase has a `serve` cmd line tool which creates a server on my `localhost` but with AppEngine I was able to run a test server that looked like `192.168.0.00:8080` which allowed me to view my website on my phone and other devices connected to my network.

Is there a way to set this up with Firebase? Or maybe a better way to test my website (with it still being **private**) on multiple devices connected to the same network? Thanks!